# Move char left or right in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I working on a simple game in assembly and for the moment I'm just trying to move the player icon (in this case it is a char X) left or right depending on whether the number 1 or 2 is hit on the keyboard. Currently I just have two if thens to move my X left or right by either decrementing or incrementing the X coordinate value. I'm using the Irvine 32 library for procs like Gotoxy to get the coordinate values. As of now my program displays the x in the right starting position but for some reason when I hit 1 or 2 the x moves up one space instead of left or right. I can't figure it out in the book I have and the things I find on the internet are not in my range of knowledge of assembly. As it stands I just want to move my char left or right. Later I will make the appropriate procs and such but for now it's a very weird problem. Any help would be appreciated.
Below is my assembly code:

```
        TITLE Matrix Rain

; Description:Dodge falling numbers to reach the final level
; Authors: John , Killian
; Revision date:2/11/2015

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
player byte 'X'; Player Character
direction byte ?; Direction the player moves
startY byte 24; Starting Y position
startX byte 39; Starting X position

breakLoop byte 9 ; base case to break

right byte 2; moves player right
left byte 1; moves player left
.code

main PROC
    ;Player Starting Point
    mov dh , startY; column 24
    mov dl,startX ; row 39
    call Gotoxy; places cursor in the middle of the bottom part of the console window
    mov al, player; Copies player character to the AL register to be printed
    call WriteChar; Prints player to screen console
    call Crlf
    ;Player Starting point
    XOR al,al; Zeroes al out
    call ReadKey;Reads keyboard 
    mov eax, 3000
    call delay

    _if1: cmp al , left
         je THEN1
         jmp ENDIF1
         THEN1:

            inc startX
            mov dl, startX
            call Gotoxy
            call Clrscr

            mov al, player
            call WriteChar
            XOR al,al
    ENDIF1:

    _if2: cmp al , right
         je THEN2
         jmp ENDIF2
         THEN2:

            dec startX
            mov dl,startX
            call Gotoxy
            call Clrscr

            mov al, player
            call WriteChar
            XOR al,al
    ENDIF2:
        exit
        main ENDP

        END main
```

Comment: Looks as if, after calling `ReadKey`, you trash `al` by calling `delay` before trying to use it.

Comment: I had put that delay in because when I tried to compare with left the x got printed at 0,0 before I put the delay in I got the same result. If I move ReadKey below that it print x in 0,0. I see what you're saying but If I compare just right for both if's when I hit 1 or 2 it moves up one space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

**1) Numbers are not characters**

```
right byte 2; moves player right
left byte 1; moves player left
```

`right` and `left` hold now the pure numbers 1 and 2. However, `ReadKey` returns in `AL` the **ASCII code** of the pressed key. You can look in a reference for the code for the keys <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> or you can write:

```
right byte '2'; moves player right
left byte '1'; moves player left
```

**2) Registers are not suitable to hold values permanently**

Although you initialize `DH` it will be changed when you reach the `call Gotoxy`. Insert a `mov dh, startY` just before calling `Gotoxy`:

```
inc startX
mov dl, startX
mov dh, startY
call Gotoxy
```

Next issue:

```
call ReadKey                ; Reads keyboard
mov eax, 3000
call delay
```

`ReadKey` returns the ASCII code of the pressed key in `AL`, but `mov eax, 3000` will destroy this result (`AL` is a part of `EAX`). [RTFM](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readkey.htm) and change the block to:

```
LookForKey:
mov  eax,50          ; sleep, to allow OS to time slice
call Delay           ; (otherwise, some key presses are lost)
call ReadKey         ; look for keyboard input
jz   LookForKey      ; no key pressed yet
```

**3) `Clrscr` changes the current cursor position**

A call to `Clrscr` destroys the effect of `Gotoxy`. Remove the calls to that function after `Gotoxy`, better remove all calls in the development phase.

---

I suggest to implement the loop right now:

```
cmp al, '3'
jne LookForKey

exit
```

This will exit the program when '3' is pressed and repeat the loop otherwise.

Comment: I call Clrscr to move the x without having an X printed for every move of the character. Do you have any thoughts as to why when I try to check for the left value it sets my X,Y back to zero when it prints.also maybe a better way to clear out the screen for my character to move.

Comment: @Jkkarr: `ClrScr` clears the screen **and** sets the cursor to top left. So the next `WriteChar` will write to top left (0,0).

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the help. I've been starting at this thing for a few days and I was reaching the point where I was going to start pulling out some hair. Thanks again. I'm gonna try your suggestions and see what happens. I think what I'll do instead of doing the number moves I'll try to use the arrow keys like I planned. I use the hex code to compare it to the keyboard scan to find that I guess.

Comment: I could kiss you right now. It actually works. I could freaking cry :D